# JS to format numbers into x an y array and divide by 2

Tags: javascript, html

How can I take this input and format into an array x,y that allows me to perform a calculation.

i.e.

input: `8458.268,19166.142,13113.780,25837.795`

divide every number by 2

to output: `4229.134,9583.071,6556.89,12918.8975`

Comment: how will be input? an array of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an appropriate callback and use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a new array with the result.

```js
var array = [8458.268, 19166.142, 13113.780, 25837.795],
    divBy2 = v => v / 2;
    result = array.map(divBy2);
    
console.log(result);
```